# Creating a second EDMX file never runs the Entity Data Model Wizard

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am trying to add a second connection in my project, and I went through the steps: got the connection string, confirmed I could access it, planned the location in the solution.

I did an Add .. New .. Data .. Entity Framework 6.x dbContext Generator
The hour glass ran for a minute, then it returned to the solution without any information collection and no EDMX record was created.  It created all of the files that would normally go under the edmx file though.  Including the file that has a pointer name back to the edmx file.

This is in Visual Studio 2015.
I also removed and reinstalled Entity Framework and tried using EF 5.x instead of 6.x in two separate projects with no EF in the main project.  No change in behaviour.

So does anyone know what could cause this and how to get around it so that I can get this last step completed?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: The Model Wizard tends to give a lot of issues with multiple models under a single project. I use separate projects for creating EDMX files to avoid issues like this one. Have not found a better solution.

Comment: Well I uninstalled Entity Framework, reinstalled Entity Framework, created two projects and added a model to one of the two projects.  The behaviour remained the same!!  Creates the files and never runs the wizard.

Comment: The EDMX wizard and toolkit kinda sucks - for people wanting to use a database-first EF6 approach, I recommend https://github.com/sjh37/EntityFramework-Reverse-POCO-Code-First-Generator - it's faster to run and eliminates the need to constantly tweak EDMX XML whenever you make DB changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I first created my edmx file I am positive that I selected the EF 6.x DbContext Generator.  Which stopped working for me after that.

What I found to make it consistently work was I have to create a New .. Data .. ADO.NET Entity Data Model and that will generate the POCO I need.  I have not experimented with how well it works with two EDMX files in one project!

But his has me working once again.